# Record from a web server camera

Tags: javascript, html, esp32

I am using an ESP32 camera and  to stream video to a browser, using a built-in web server. I want to record the video stream on the browser and one technique I am looking at is getUserMedia/MediaRecorder. However, it looks like getUserMedia 'sees' only the devices that are directly attached to the pc, so no input device is found.

So, how do I specify the web server as the source of the video?

```
  const startStream = () => {
view.src = `${streamUrl}/stream`
show(viewContainer)
streamButton.innerHTML = 'Stop Stream'  }
```

6th Sept:

I have taken the code from the example and added in my cam src but this isn't displaying or recording anything :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Train Cam</title>
    <video width="300" id="vid"  src="http://192.168.1.194:81/stream" autoplay controls></video>
    <video width="300" id="result" style="display: none" controls></video>
    <button id="start">Start recording</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop recording</button>
  </head>
  <script>
    const video = document.querySelector('#vid')
    const result = document.querySelector('#result')
    const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')
    const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop')
    const chunks = []

    video.addEventListener('play', () => {
      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(video.captureStream())

    startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      recorder.start()
    })

    stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      recorder.stop()
    })

    recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      chunks.push(e.data)
    }

    recorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' })
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      result.src = url;
      result.style.display = 'block'
    }
    })


  </script>
 </html>
```

The following code is, what I think, the relevant parts of the existing code that works, displaying the cam stream:

```
     <figure>
      <div id="stream-container" class="image-container hidden">
        <div class="close" id="close-stream">×</div>
        <img id="stream" src="" />
      </div>
    </figure>
    
    var streamUrl = baseHost + ":81";
    
    const view = document.getElementById("stream");
    const viewContainer = document.getElementById("stream-container");
    const streamButton = document.getElementById("toggle-stream");
    
    const startStream = () => {
      view.src = `${streamUrl}/stream`;
      show(viewContainer);
      streamButton.innerHTML = "Stop Stream";
    };

    streamButton.onclick = () => {
      const streamEnabled = streamButton.innerHTML === "Stop Stream";
      if (streamEnabled) {
        stopStream();
      } else {
        startStream();
      }
    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `MediaRecorder` with `video.captureStream()` on the `<video>` element you're binding the camera footage with

Comment: Thanks for that but could you give me a bit more information. Ie how I would code it?

Comment: Sure, here you go, an example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/wilkoklak/pen/rNepLNX). You have to read more about URL.createObjectURL and what you can do with it to make it downloadable

Comment: This looks like it it's exactly what I'm after! Let the cogs go round a few times and hopefully a penny will drop. I may be back with more questions.... but thanks!

Comment: Hi, @wilkoklak, I've tried what I thought was the answer (and many others) but I can't get my stream to display. I've taken the code you showed me in the CodePen and I've added what I thought was my src:                                                         
<video width="300" id="vid"  src="http://192.168.1.194" autoplay controls></video>

Comment: or  src="http://192.168.1.194:81/stream"  However, the src is showing in the inspection window as unknown or empty response. Any clues? Sorry about the formatting but I don't understand how to do it in comments (despite reading the 'help')

Comment: try adding http - `src="http://192.168.1.194:81/stream"`

Comment: that was one of the options I tried too